# Get first value of each thread with first query and use the value to perform a second query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My first query returns the thread_id where `is_root` is true

```
SELECT thread_id FROM event_comments WHERE e_id = 1 and is_root = true ORDER BY date_posted DESC
```

[image]

How would I then get all the messages from each thread using the thread_id?

```
SELECT * FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id = 'ac7672dd-5465-42ca-a887-273f7641c972' ORDER BY date_posted
```

```
SELECT * FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id = '33da63a3-d324-4767-a294-75cdeaf478d8' ORDER BY date_posted
```

I am not sure how I can combine these two queries to get this expected output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can use `exists` with a correlated subquery:

```
select * 
from event_comments e
where exists (
    select 1
    from event_comments e1
    where e1.e_id = 1 and e1.is_root = true and e1.thread_id = e.thread_id
)
order by thread_id, date_posted
```

`exists` is safer than `in` because it properly handle `null` values. `in` is tricky with `null`s: if any of the values returned by the subquery is `null`, then all records will match in the outer query.

---

**Edit**

To order the results starting by thread, starting with the thread that has the most recent message, and then by descending date of message in the thread, you can do:

```
select * 
from event_comments e
where exists (
    select 1
    from event_comments e1
    where e1.e_id = 1 and e1.is_root = true and e1.thread_id = e.thread_id
)
order by 
    max(date_posted) over(partition by thread_id),
    date_posted desc
```

Comment: It's not quite returning the order I need https://i.imgur.com/5wHr1oT.png not sure why

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES: I fixed the `order by` clause. If I understand correctly, you want results ordered by `thread_id`, then `date_posted`.

Comment: it's still giving me a bit of an unexpected output. I can't figure out how to order the thread_ids by date_posted and then the thread ordered by date_posted. I drew out a diagram of the messages https://i.imgur.com/g5bzUor.png

Comment: the query you gave me is extremely close, except 1 row should be at the bottom https://i.imgur.com/nptGju9.png

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES: I think that I see what you mean. I edited my answer.

Comment: It works! https://i.imgur.com/w8BSTlX.png Thanks so much for your help :) been working on it for hours, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id in (SELECT thread_id FROM event_comments WHERE e_id = 1 and is_root = true) ORDER BY date_posted
```